# Using GCloud CLI with Docker image

Tags: docker, gcloud

I'm using the official Google Cloud SDK Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/) to use the GCloud CLI on my workstation, since I have some restrictions on directly installing things on this machine. One of my main issues is that whenever I SSH into my instance, the SSH key generation process is repeated. I followed the instructions listed in the info section of the docker image. The command I'm using to login is -

```
docker run --rm -ti --volumes-from gcloud-config google/cloud-sdk gcloud compute --project "dummy" ssh --zone "asia-southeast1-a" "test"
```

How do I make the SSH login persist as would be the case if I was using the GCLoud CLI on my host machine?

Comment: So you means your VM in the cloud, rotates the SSH keys?

Comment: I don't know. I'm new to Google Cloud Platform. I ran the `auth login` command as listed on Docker Hub and am using --volumes-from the gcloud-config.

Comment: I hope you are using auth login only once?

Comment: Yes, only once.

Comment: Add the complete output from your command execution